# Connect Linux via ssh from windows

Tags: java, linux, command-line, ssh

My desktop is windows. And I would like to connect a Linux server remotely. The middle target is to using script to ssh(using password, not key pairs) remote linux server from windows and run a command. I have putty installed in my machine. The final target here is that I could use java to collect output from this script(remote connect a server via ssh password and run a command) and then parse the output and extract the data I want and put it in excel sheet. The remote server needs login and password.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)?

Comment: I downloaded jsch, see the example Exec.java. I simply could not connect remote server. Remote server use ssh password. But I got following error message: "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey:xxxxx". I do not know where to put my ssh password. (it is not login password).

Answer (score 2):

use [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) of jcraft

here is one example

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/JTAJSch.java

you can find it on SO as well

[Jsch or SSHJ or Ganymed SSH-2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097514/jsch-or-sshj-or-ganymed-ssh-2)

Comment: I downloaded jsch, see the example Exec.java. I simply could not connect remote server. Remote server use ssh password. But I got following error message: "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey:xxxxx". I do not know where to put my ssh password. (it is not login password).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097514/jsch-or-sshj-or-ganymed-ssh-2 for nikunj's answer its working fine here is line `Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);`

Comment: try{
      JSch jsch=new JSch();  

      String host=null;
      if(arg.length>0){
        host=arg[0];
      }
      else{
        host=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter username@hostname",
                                         System.getProperty("user.name")+
                                         "@localhost"); 
      }
      String user=host.substring(0, host.indexOf('@'));
      host=host.substring(host.indexOf('@')+1);
      
      Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host,2030);

Comment: port here is 2030 and it uses password as SSH password, not key pair.

Comment: ssh port is 22, and just make sure that user and hosts are valid

Comment: I change port to 22, then it says "Tha authenticity of hos 'XX.XXX.XXX.XX' can't be established. RSA key fingerprint is a2:18:44:43:15:0b:ca:6f:93:cc:af:16:04:3c:48:35, Are you sure you want to continue connecting?"

Comment: have you tried to login with your credentials using putty? if not then check that

Comment: Yes, putty does not work either. But in the work, we are only allowed to use remote server with port 2030. From windows to remote Linux, there are some firewall.

Comment: then port forwarding must be enabled on remote machine, can u login with putty on 2030 port?

Comment: @Nirmal-thInkbeYond let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/962/discussion-between-user84592-and-nirmal-think-beyond)

Comment: Yes. you are right. I shall whether port forwarding is enable or not.

Answer (score 0):

you could run [plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) (from PuTTY's developers) for running batches and writing the output to files, then process that with Java.
I'm not sure how simple linking Java to PuTTY would be.