# Execute a unix program from a Java class using java.lang.Process with a specific user

Tags: java, unix

I am trying to run a unix command from Java using java.lang.Process class.
How can we pass a specific user so that the command executes with the permissions of that specific user ?
I don't want to execute the command with a superuser.

Comment: AFAIK You can't do that. The process is forked from the current process and runs with the Java process' user.

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the very purpose of having security and permissions?

Comment: I don't think it's possible -> http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/25282-how-run-command-some-other-user-id.html

Comment: @AniketThakur it does not defeat the purpose, imagine a process that want's to downgrade  it's rights (e.g. apache daemon runnig from root, or some other) in order not to allow an attacker to  break in, that process changes it's user.

Comment: @csoroiu That is the point. Yes you can do whatever you want from the root/SU but from one user you cannot execute the process in the name of other user who has it's execution rights(which you don't). Try creating a file in /tmp and then try to view it by ls from another user.

Comment: Please have a look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a ssh session, that logs with the user you know its password and run a specific command.

E.g. using java shell [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)

or

[Expect4J](http://code.google.com/p/expect4j/)

or

[Ganymed-ssh-2](http://code.google.com/p/ganymed-ssh-2/)

I found a good thread here by the way:
[Jsch or SSHJ or Ganymed SSH-2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097514/jsch-or-sshj-or-ganymed-ssh-2)

Comment: I can't see how sudo would help you here.

Answer (score 1):

You could start a `login` command first and then input credentials into it.

I would guess that starting `su - [USER]` should do the trick.

After reading through `apropos user` I came across the `pkexec` command which should do what you need.

Comment: this can be tried, additionally you could send programatically the password to the `su -` command, haven't tried but could work.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a new shell and execute commands which will switch to another user and then run the programm